# SQL Error Regarding apostrophe from datagridview using parameter in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

```
Dim sc = datagridview.rows(0).cells(0).value
cmd = New SqlCommand("insert into Schedule (Name) values(@sc)", con)
with cmd
                .Connection = con
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sc", sc.cells(0))
end with
```

The value from the datagrid view contains an apostrophe where I get an error in ('s). Any work around with this?

EDIT:
This is the error:

> SqlException was unhandled. Incorrect syntax near 's'.

EDIT 2: i've revised the code to this:

```
for 1=0 to datagridview.rows.count -1 
Dim tname = datagridview.Rows(i)
cmd = New SqlCommand("insert into Schedule (Name) values(@sc)", con)
with cmd
                 .Connection = con
                 .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                 .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sc", sc.cells(0).value) 
 end with
 con.Close() 
 con.Open()  
 If Not cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 Then
    con.Close()
    Exit For
 End If
 next
```

Error is still the same.

Comment: Please don't use [AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) also read [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: And what error do you get?

Comment: Does `sc` have a `.cells` property? In the Dim statement, there is `.cells(0).value`, and then in the parameter the code is using `sc.cells(0)`. I recommend that you set [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project (and set it as the default for new projects) so that Visual Studio can point out problems like that for you.

Comment: Still getting the error even after option strict and option explicit on

Comment: What is the data type and size of the "Name" column in the database?

Comment: It was nvarchar(max) @AndrewMorton

Comment: what other alternatives can i use to replace addwithvalue @GuidoG

Comment: @theck Have you read the articles ?

Comment: yes, those are the codes i use when i learned vb.net. changes to addwithvalue after some times. im still learning with vb.net since im not an IT grad.  Btw, thank you for the useful article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it goes through all the values quickly in one go, I would make the connection once and change the value of the parameter for each iteration, like this:

```
Dim sql = "INSERT INTO [Schedule] ([Name]) VALUES(@sc)"

Using conn As New SqlConnection("your connection string"),
       cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@sc",
                       .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                       .Size = -1})

    conn.Open()

    For i = 0 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim tname = dgv.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        cmd.Parameters("@sc").Value = tname
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next

End Using
```

Including the size of the parameter in its declaration helps SQL Server keep things tidy (it only needs one entry in the query cache).

The [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) statement makes sure that the connection and command are disposed of properly when they are finished with.

The purpose of checking `If Not cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0` was not clear to me, so I didn't put that in.
(I used "dgv" as the name of the DataGridView.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the " ' " by " '' "

```
Dim sc = datagridview.rows(0).cells(0).value
cmd = New SqlCommand("insert into Schedule (Name) values(@sc)", con)
with cmd
                .Connection = con
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sc", replace(sc.cells(0), "'", "''")
end with
```

/**** EDIT ****/
I will consider by the way that your code have a problem with the affectation of the value. You get the value into SC then try to get again the value from cell

```
Dim sc = datagridview.rows(0).cells(0).value
cmd = New SqlCommand("insert into Schedule (Name) values(@sc)", con)
with cmd
                .Connection = con
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .Parameters("@sc").value = sc.replace("'", "''")
end with
```

Comment: When using parameters this should not be necessary. The OP needs to post the error he is getting, as it stands we have no clue to what is going on

Comment: This is the error:

> SqlException was unhandled. Incorrect syntax near 's'.

Comment: Then try the replace and let me know the error

Comment: tried this "'.Parameters("@sc").value = replace(sc, "'", "''") " but no avail. @chrisferreira

Comment: Sorry, the syntax is string.replace. Just edit the code sc.replace("'", "''")